# Node.js - Need assistance on converting this function to async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

The below function works well. However my database loops is waiting to complete each 'request' output, before it goes to next record. What I wanted to achieve is, I need to loop through all rows an fire 'request' call. Let the 'request' takes its own time to finish the result

```
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query(sqlQuery, function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    forEach(result, function(item, index) {
      var done = this.async();
      var varID = item.id;
      var options = {
        url: 'https://apps........../user/delete',
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'request',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'token': 'xxxxx'
        }
      };
      request
        .post(options)
        .on('response', function(response) {
          // console.log(response.statusCode + '-' + response.statusMessage) // 200
          console.log('Deleting Member: ' + varID) // 'image/png'
          log.setLevel('info');
          log.info(response.statusCode + '-' + response.statusMessage, logdate);
          log.info('Deleting Member: ' + varID, logdate);
          done();
        })
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You can just remove `done()` from the response part of your callback and the line `this.async()` from the `forEach` loop. This will make the function execute without waiting for the query.

Comment: Thank you drinchev